# How do I cat a file on the filesystem from within Jenkins' Groovy

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins

In Jenkins, how do I cat a file that's in my filesystem and not part of any job's workspace?

Comment: Why Groovy ? Why just not use `cat {absolute_path_to_your_file}` in `Execute Shell` build step ?

Comment: In this case, I'm looking to do something once and not have it be part of a Jenkins job (I needed to retrieve the data in a file when I didn't have ssh access to the Jenkins machine).

Comment: so what's the problem if you put this task into jenkins job ? no so clear on what you want to achieve.

Comment: A Jenkins job is too heavy-weight when all I want to do is this one-off thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to "manage jenkins", then "script console."  To cat your file, substitute your file name and path for `/var/lib/jenkins/evn.sh` in the below code, paste the code into the box, and hit "Run":

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc ='cat /var/lib/jenkins/env.sh'.execute()

proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
return sout
```

Comment: move this to the question area instead of answer.

Comment: Why move it?  This is an answer, not part of the question.